# How to return SerialException error message, Object Serial?

Tags: python, serialization, serial-port, pyserial

How to return Error message that output by SerialException? In here i try to open port in port that already open. I want to get error that occurs. In the case SerialException will return **Access is denied**

> could not open port 'COM38': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.',
>   None, 5)

```
import serial
from serial import SerialException

def open:
  try:
    serial.Serial('COM38', 9600)

    return True
  except SerialException:
    #How to return error message that serial exception occurs?
    return Raise

print(open())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help.

```
import serial
from serial import SerialException

def open:
  try:
    serial.Serial('COM38', 9600)

    return True
  except PermissionError as e:
      message = str(e)
      raise SerialException(message)
  except SerialException as ex:
      print(ex)

print(open())
```